# connect to my VPS PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm have VPS on install PostgreSQL
It working using console putty

but if i'm try to connect using pgAdmin 3 on my home Computer, it's
 print error

> could not connect to server: Connection refused  (0x0000274D/10061)
>   Is the server running on host "x.x.x.x" and accepting TCP/IP
>   connections on port 5432?

my config next

postgresql.conf

```
listen_addresses = '*'  what IP address(es) to listen on;
port = 5432             # (change requires restart)
```

and pg_hba.conf(im try all combinations localhost,192.168... etc)

```
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             all                     md5
# IPv6 local connections:
```

Comment: try using IP, not hostname "ip server"

Comment: im use real ip, im change its

Comment: well, if you connect with putty - I assume you ssh to VPS and then connect locally - right?.. then check if connection is not firewalled at all - try connecting to postgres on external IP from putty session... that's for the beginning

Answer (score 0):

You should:

1. Check your iptables rules (with `iptables -L`). Many distros have a bunch of restrictive rules by default.
2. Check if postgres is really listening on port with `netstat -plant | grep 5432`. If it does, then you'll see line with it. If it doesn't, then you probably have some typo in config and you should check postgresql logs.

Comment: im run netstat -plant | grep 5432, but nothing happend

Comment: Then your postgres server haven't actually started. Check its logs to check why. If you copy-pasted snippet from `postgresql.conf` correctly, then it is probably `#` missing before comment on line with `listen_addres`. It should be



`listen_addresses = '*'  #what IP address(es) to listen on;`

Comment: listen_addresses = '*'  # what IP address(es) to listen on;
     # comma-separated list of addresses;
     # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
     # (change requires restart)
port = 5432    # (change requires restart)

Comment: `listen_addresses = ''` should be `listen_addresses = '*'`